# What verb describes the motion of a swimmer's arms?

Tags: single-word-requests

This question was raised in an [XKCD What-If post](https://what-if.xkcd.com/124/) (in footnote 3):

> When a swimmer is submerged and moving at top speed, the drag from the water is equal to the thrust they generate by kicking and ... whatever the gerund form of the verb is for the things your arms do while swimming. My first thought was "stroking", but it's definitely not that.

What is the verb to use to describe what the swimmer's arms do?

Comment: I think "stroking" would work fine in this context. The arm movements in swimming are often referred to as a "stroke". You could say "paddling", but "stroke" conjures a more graceful image.

Comment: Submerged = fully underwater, not gliding on the surface partially submerged?

Comment: I don't think being submerged is important to the word choice here.

Comment: Depends on the swimmer, doesn’t it? If the swimmer is me, for example, _flailing_ would probably be apt.

Comment: I don't at all understand physics, so I won't dare answer lest I make a fool of myself. But could you just use *propelling*? As in, "... the drag from the water is equal to the thrust they generate by *propelling themselves forward.*" It's just as many words as "kicking and flailing."

Comment: 'Stroking' has an unfortunate second connotation.

Comment: @EFrog the question is about a verb that applies specifically to the arms, as opposed to the legs.

Comment: @AE especially when combined with "kicking".

Comment: Given the difference between strokes I doubt there's a single word that covers the range of arm movements but is still specific enough -- even in context -- to be unambiguously about swimming.  That said, for front/back crawl (i.e. swimming on the surface, so there is a difference) how about *windmilling* (at a beginner level anyway).  Not close enough to the Q to be an answer though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***pulling*** might work

From the site [USASwimming.org](http://usaswimming.org/ViewNewsArticle.aspx?TabId=0&itemid=4246&mid=8712)

> Their arms pull while their legs are streamlined, and the legs kick while their upper body is streamlined.

Comment: I'd say the *pull* is only half of a full arm stroke (the other half being the recovery)

Comment: @blgt- I agree, but in this specific context the word is being used to describe the thrust generation portion of the stroke: "the drag from the water is equal to the thrust they generate by kicking and <pulling of the arms>"  I will agree that an argument could be made that once the hands pass the shoulder it becomes pushing.

Comment: I agree (thus the +1), I'm just pointing out it's important to make the distinction. It's *more specific* (and also a better parallel for `kicking`) in the OP's context than what OP asked about. On a side note, *pushing* works just as well (as referring to the arm pushing the water)

Comment: It bothers me if 'pushing' and 'pulling' could be used to mean the same thing here. Is there evidence that one of them (or a different word) is more commonly used? I don't want to rely on my own intuition / experience in this case, hence the question.

Comment: @danarmak They don't mean the same thing. You *pull* your hand towards your body, you *push* your hand against the water

Comment: @blgt if I were to write `the swimmer was kicking with his legs and pushing and pulling with his arms`, I don't feel it would be very clear.

Comment: Indeed, however both `kicking with his legs and pushing with his arms` and `kicking with his legs and pulling with his arms` look perfectly fine to me

Comment: Very well, I'll have to accept that this answer is imperfect but there's no better one. Thanks!

Comment: @blgt - the pulling and pushing to which I was referring is that I'm * pulling* my body through the water when my hands are in front of my head but my arm stroke continues such that when my shoulders are ahead of my hands I am now pushing my body through the water.

Answer (score 0):

> When a swimmer is submerged and moving at top speed, the drag from the water is equal to the thrust they generate by kicking and **sweeping their arms**.

[ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/sweep) defines the corresponding noun *sweep* thus:

> NOUN
>
> 2 A long, swift, curving movement:
>
> *a grandiose sweep of his hand*

The advantage of this choice is that unlike *pulling,* it is a general term that does not specify whether the thrust (which is the desired outcome of the swimmer's movements) is achieved by pulling or pushing with the arms.

Comment: When I read this, I see, "...kicking and sweeping their arms," as in, "kicking their arms and sweeping their arms." So if *sweep* were used, I would want it to say, "... kicking their legs and sweeping their arms," for the parallel. I think that's why the OP was looking for a single word... A perfect one probably doesn't exist though.

Comment: @EFrog - You're right, it could be misinterpreted. But the ambiguity can be resolved easily, simply by reversing the order of description for the movements of the arms and legs: "When a swimmer is submerged and moving at top speed, the drag from the water is equal to the thrust they generate by **sweeping their arms and kicking".**

Comment: @ErikKowai Oh, that's better. I like that.

Comment: But it does depend on the stroke being performed- the sidestroke, for example, does not use a sweeping arm motion.

Comment: @Jim - Any motion of the arm away from the body is a sweeping motion.